# What happened to a.out

Tags: executable, binary, elf

I just started to wonder what ever happened to the original a.out binary file format and why it was superseded by ELF?

Comment: `a.out` is still available (check compiler options), but ELF is more featureful. Read `man elf readelf` and see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.out

Comment: I'd like to do more reading on this but I guess it had to do with Linux having a inflexible jump table architecture.  As is noted here: https://web.archive.org/web/20190220015720/docs.freebsd.org/doc/2.2.7-RELEASE/usr/share/doc/FAQ/FAQ204.html.  I'd be interested in what the architecture was and how it differed from SunOS as it is noted in the freebsd thread